# Unexpected value 'CacheService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

I'm following the code samples on this https://maurogarcia.dev/maurogarcia.dev/posts/client-side-caching-with-angular/ blog post to add client-side caching to my project.

I've added the cache.service.ts, http-client.service.ts code and wired them into a component that invokes  the code, but when the component is invoked, I am getting a null object ref exception.

If I try to register the components in
@NgModule in either declaration, imports, etc. I get an error that the registration is incorrect.

in declaration:

> Unexpected value 'CacheService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

in imports:

> Unexpected value 'CacheService' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

the library service:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientService } from '../cache/http-client.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
// for model
import { Path } from './path';
import { Topic } from './topic';
import { Sector } from './sector';

export class LibraryService {
  public sectors: Sector[];
  private api;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClientService, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.api = baseUrl + 'sector';
  }

// this._http throws error as undefined
  getAll(): Observable<Sector[]> {
    return this._http.get<Sector[]>({ url: this.api, cacheMins: 5 })
  }
}

export interface Library {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  about: string;
  topics: Topic[];
  paths: Path[];
  sector: Sector;
}
```

*** app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FetchLibraryComponent } from './libraries/library.component';
import { FetchLibrariesComponent } from './libraries/libraries.component';
import { CacheService } from './cache/cache.service';
import { HttpClientService } from './cache/http-client.service';
import { LibraryService } from './model/library';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    ...
    CacheService,
    FetchLibrariesComponent,
    FetchLibraryComponent,
    ...

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
...
      { path: 'libraries', component: FetchLibrariesComponent },
      { path: 'libraries/:id', component: FetchLibraryComponent },
    ...
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*** caching service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class CacheService {
  constructor() { }

  save(options: LocalStorageSaveOptions) {
    // Set default values for optionals
    options.expirationMins = options.expirationMins || 0

    // Set expiration date in miliseconds
    const expirationMS = options.expirationMins !== 0 ? options.expirationMins * 60 * 1000 : 0

    const record = {
      value: typeof options.data === 'string' ? options.data : JSON.stringify(options.data),
      expiration: expirationMS !== 0 ? new Date().getTime() + expirationMS : null,
      hasExpiration: expirationMS !== 0 ? true : false
    }
    localStorage.setItem(options.key, JSON.stringify(record))
  }

  load(key: string) {
    // Get cached data from localstorage
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (item !== null) {
      const record = JSON.parse(item)
      const now = new Date().getTime()
      // Expired data will return null
      if (!record || (record.hasExpiration && record.expiration <= now)) {
        return null
      } else {
        return JSON.parse(record.value)
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  remove(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key)
  }

  cleanLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.clear()
  }
}

export class LocalStorageSaveOptions {
  key: string
  data: any
  expirationMins?: number
}
```

*** http-client.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { CacheService } from './cache.service'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

export enum Verbs {
  GET = 'GET',
  PUT = 'PUT',
  POST = 'POST',
  DELETE = 'DELETE'
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _cacheService: CacheService,
  ) { }

  get<T>(options: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpCall(Verbs.GET, options)
  }

  delete<T>(options: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpCall(Verbs.DELETE, options)
  }

  post<T>(options: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpCall(Verbs.POST, options)
  }

  put<T>(options: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpCall(Verbs.PUT, options)
  }

  private httpCall<T>(verb: Verbs, options: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {

    // Setup default values
    options.body = options.body || null
    options.cacheMins = options.cacheMins || 0

    if (options.cacheMins > 0) {
      // Get data from cache
      const data = this._cacheService.load(options.url)
      // Return data from cache
      if (data !== null) {
        return of<T>(data)
      }
    }

    return this.http.request<T>(verb, options.url, {
      body: options.body
    })
      .pipe(
        switchMap(response => {
          if (options.cacheMins > 0) {
            // Data will be cached
            this._cacheService.save({
              key: options.url,
              data: response,
              expirationMins: options.cacheMins
            })
          }
          return of<T>(response)
        })
      )
  }
}

export class HttpOptions {
  url: string
  body?: any
  cacheMins?: number
}
```

Comment: Hi @James, can you attach your cache.service.ts to your question. Meanwhile, based on the error message, your `CacheService` is not Angular Module nor Angular Component, thus you cannot apply it in `declarations` and `imports` in app.module.ts

Comment: First, thank you for your interest. And yes of course,  you wish, but as I mentioned, that code was stolen (close to verbatim) from 
https://maurogarcia.dev/maurogarcia.dev/posts/client-side-caching-with-angular/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **CacheService** is not a **Component**. Therefore remove it from `declarations` array of **AppModule**.

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    ...
    CacheService, // remove this
    FetchLibrariesComponent,
    FetchLibraryComponent,
    ...

  ],
```

Add `providedIn: 'root'` metadata to @Injectable annotation of **CacheService** like below. Then you can use it anywhere in the application.

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheService
```

I noticed you have forgotten to annotate your **LibraryService**. Add the `@Injectable` annotation to that too. Then the mentioned issue will have gone.

Comment: OMG that was it. Adding  providedIn: 'root'.

Johna, I really appreciate your guidance. +1 in life.

Answer (score 0):

### ISSUE

Based on the error message, your CacheService is not Angular Module nor Angular Component, thus you cannot apply it in declarations and imports in app.module.ts.

in declaration:

> Unexpected value 'CacheService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

in imports:

> Unexpected value 'CacheService' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

---

### SOLUTIONS

**Solution 1: Providing service in service**

Thus, to inject `CacheService` to `HttpClientService`, you can do as below:

> client.service.ts

```
import { CacheService } from <<your relative cache.service.ts path>>;

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(CacheService) private _cacheService: CacheService,
  ) { }

  ...
}
```

> library.service.ts

```
import { HttpClientService } from <<your relative client.service.ts path>>;

@Injectable()
export class LibraryService {
  ...
  constructor(
    @Inject(HttpClientService) private _http: HttpClientService,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

---

**Solution 2: Inject service in root**

If you would like to share your `CacheService` and `HttpClientService` for app.module.ts, you can do in this way:

> cache.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheService {
  ...
}
```

> client.service.ts

```
import { CacheService } from <<your relative cache.service.ts path>>;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    deps: [CacheService, HttpClient]
})
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _cacheService: CacheService,
  ) { }

  ...
}
```

> library.service.ts

```
import { HttpClientService } from <<your relative client.service.ts path>>;

@Injectable()
export class LibraryService {
  ...
  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClientService,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, and forgive me if I wasn't clear, but the issue is happening in LibraryService.  this.http is undefined, even though it is passed into the constructor.  it blows up on this line: 
    return this._http.get<Sector[]>({ url: this.api, cacheMins: 5 })

Comment: Hi @James, thanks for the feedback, I had updated my solution 1, I miss out on Inject HtppClientService to LibraryService. Meanwhile, you can also look at solution 2. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun. You have not annotated your **LibraryService** with **@Injectable**. That is why the **this._http** is undefined.

Comment: Hi @Johna, just found out this missing part. Thanks a lot for the feedback. =)